# Strange file/folder permission errors on Drupal 8.8.5

Tags: php, apache, drupal, centos, drupal-8

I'm facing very strange behaviour on **Drupal 8.8.5**, CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804, PHP 7.2.19 and HTTPD - Apache/2.4.6

Basically, after updating to 8.8.5 (that has been a real headache), the system throws errors while **flushing css+js** files on "flush caches".

> Drupal\Core\File\Exception\FileException: Failed to unlink file
>   'public://css/css_Y3zRgmC0P7yIXk_w_H9qyrPs3aMkKRv44SMfupbSCMc.css.gz'.
>   in Drupal\Core\File\FileSystem->delete() (line 340
>   of/var/www/html/project/core/lib/Drupal/Core/File/FileSystem.php).
>
> Warning:
>   unlink(/var/www/html/project/sites/default/files/css/css_Y3zRgmC0P7yIXk_w_H9qyrPs3aMkKRv44SMfupbSCMc.css.gz):
>   Permission denied in Drupal\Core\File\FileSystem->unlink() (line 124
>   of /var/www/html/synergie/core/lib/Drupal/Core/File/FileSystem.php)

This obviously leads to bad frontend and admin panel behaviour.

I've literally tried to do everything I could, by:

1. Setting all 777 to **/var/www/html/project/sites/default** and subdirectories
2. Changing owner of the directory aforementioned
3. Manually debugging lines 124 and 340 of lib/Drupal/Core/File/FileSystem.php

What I've found very strange, is that by manually debugging the *unlink* method on *FileSystem.php*, it lead to some strange results:

*public://css/css_Y3zRgmC0P7yIXk_w_H9qyrPs3aMkKRv44SMfupbSCMc.css.gz*: **readable and writable**

*/var/www/html/project/sites/default/files/css/css_Y3zRgmC0P7yIXk_w_H9qyrPs3aMkKRv44SMfupbSCMc.css.gz*: **readable but not writable**

Some notes:
- Httpd runs on *apache* user and *apache* group

- I've tried to do every possible combination of folder and write permission and owner and group to every directory and child subdirectories of */var/www/html/project/sites/*
- I've already tried to follow these instructions: [Web Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20141106100939/http://sandu.camerzan.md/content/fix-file-upload-error-could-not-move-uploaded-file-drupal-7-how)
- I've also run this "folder and file permissions script": [Drupal Website](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924)

Do you have ideas or suggestions? I cannot go past this one

Comment: If you use sudo or su to change to the apache user, are you able to delete it? I would start checking there. If that works.

Comment: If your files and folders are owned by `apache`, setting folders to `700` and files to `600` should work (not code. files in your files directory)

Comment: Hi @rovr138, thank you for your hint. I've actually tried to do what you suggested by doing "su -s /bin/bash apache" (because in /etc/passwd the apache user is set to /sbin/nologin). Strange thing: it works. Files are deletable. And the other strange thing is that i can also delete "root" files from the apache user. I don't know what is happening under the hoods, but I've never seen such a thing on a Linux machine :(

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like SELinux blocking...

Find current mode of SELinux and temporarily shut it down.

```
Getenforce # see current mode.
Sudo setenforce 0 # shut it down.
```

Try your thing. If that’s cause, just add rule to allow locations like /var/www/your Docroot